# Passing PHP variable to Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm trying to pass a php variable to javascript, but it doesn't seem to be working. I know that it works with just the javascript, just that it doesn't work when I'm trying to pass it with PHP. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$sayIt = "Hello";

echo "
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance($sayIt);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

</script>
";

?>
```

Comment: Try `var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('$sayIt');` (single quotes)

Comment: This question is answerable by debugging the code with [debugging tools](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) available in your browser. Watch out for _errors_. [Rubber Duck Debug](http://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code. If you are not sure what your code does, use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) or [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger). Only _then_, ask a question on StackOverflow and _show your research_.

Comment: @Rasclatt It doesn't seem to work in an ajax call.

Comment: I hate the phrase *it doesn't work*.. For next time, explain yourself: what's not working? Do you have any error? Did you open browser's console? Can you post html *PHP-post-processed*? Anyway, take a look at @FrankLi's answer..

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because the PHP will interpret the code like this:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(Hello);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

</script>
```

Then JavaScript will consider the Hello as a variable, which may not defined in JavaScript, you may should write it like this:

```
echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(\"$sayIt\");

window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

";
```

Then it will be interpreted to this:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello");
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

</script>
```

Hope it will help you!